# ES6 Function result is showing NaN

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have make a ES6 class function, I can't understand why the console result is showing NaN

```js
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, dob) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthday = new Date(dob);
    }

    greeting() {
        return `Hello there, This is ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }

    calculateAge() {
        const diff = Date.now() - this.birthday.getTime();
        const ageDate = new Date(diff);
        return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1995);
    }
}

const niran = new Person('Niran', 'Yousuf', '26-12-1992');

console.log(niran.calculateAge());
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? `console.log(niran.birthday)` -> `Invalid Date`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the string that you are sending to the Date object on line 5. Just change the values like new Date(26,12,1992).

The syntax for Date object is :

new Date()

new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

new Date(milliseconds)

new Date(date string)

Check out the docs at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for Date is:

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

Also there is no such thing (without a library) as `DateInterval` like you can in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the date diff logic. The problem lies in your difference and how you are passing the date

```
var date1 = new Date("7/13/2010"); // this is your birth year
var date2 = new Date(); // This is your current date
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

Rest is all logic to calculate date